# Pantheon Greeter Clock Alignment / Loki

Tags: release-loki, greeter

I've noticed as of 7th July 2017 that the clock on the Pantheon greeter is misaligned to the right of the screen (after updating). At 8:30 in the morning I noticed that the 'M' in 'AM' was cut off - this is on a 1920x1080 screen. If this helps, I have the text size set to 'Large' in the system settings.

Thanks everyone!

William

EDIT: This seems to happen regardless of resolution, have now noticed this on my desktop with 1360x768 screen. This has not been updated for roughly three/four days.

Comment: I would suggest opening a bug in the greeter issue queue: https://github.com/elementary/greeter/issues also try to include a screenshot / photo.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if it was an update or cold reboot that fixed it but it seems to be working correctly again.

Thanks either way ^_^b

William

**EDIT:** On closer inspection over the past three weeks I have noticed that this occurs only on **Fridays**. On other days of the week, the formatting is correct but does tend to nearly crop in the same manner.